# Unable to solve coupled differential equations using DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

can anyone please help solving this simple coupled differential equations analytically? The solution should be some cosine actually..

````
x1Eqn = {x1'[t] == I*omr*(Conjugate[x2[t]] - x2[t]), x1[0] == 1}
x2Eqn = {x2'[t] == -I*omr*(2*x1[t] - 1.0), x2[0] == 0}

constXSol = DSolve[{x1Eqn, x2Eqn}, {x1[t], x2[t]}, t]
```
````

Comment: Mathematica evaluates `constXSol={}` ! No solution exists!

Comment: First, use ``1`` instead of ``1.0``. Second, what is ``omr``? Is it supposed to be a real number? Third, if you remove initial conditions ``x1[0] == 1`` and ``x2[0] == 0``, you will get a solution, but it is non-elementary, with integrals. Lastly, are you sure you have your equations right? Where did you get the "cosine" solution?

Comment: **this simple coupled differential** I do not think this is simple.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that `Conjugate[]` is difficult to deal with. So would be `Im[]` if you simplified the first equation.  It's probably best to break the variables down into real and imaginary parts:

```
neweqs = {x1Eqn, x2Eqn} /. 
       {x1 -> Function[t, x1R[t] + I x1I[t]], 
        x2 -> Function[t, x2R[t] + I x2I[t]]} //
      Map[ReIm, #, {3}] & //
     Simplify[#, {x1R[t], x1R'[t], x1I[t], x1I'[t], x2R[t], x2R'[t], 
        x2I[t], x2I'[t], x1R[0], Derivative[1][x1R][0], x1I[0], 
        Derivative[1][x1I][0], x2R[0], Derivative[1][x2R][0], x2I[0], 
        Derivative[1][x2I][0], t, omr} \[Element] Reals] & //
   Map[Thread, #, {2}] & //
  Flatten
(*
{Derivative[1][x1R][t] == 2 omr x2I[t], 
  Derivative[1][x1I][t] == 0, 
  x1R[0] == 1, x1I[0] == 0, 
 Derivative[1][x2R][t] == 2 omr x1I[t], 
  Derivative[1][x2I][t] == omr - 2 omr x1R[t], 
  x2R[0] == 0, x2I[0] == 0}
*)

DSolve[neweqs, {x1R[t], x1I[t], x2R[t], x2I[t]}, t]
(*
{{x1R[t] -> 1/2 (Cos[2 omr t] + Cos[2 omr t]^2 + Sin[2 omr t]^2), 
  x2I[t] -> -(1/2) Sin[2 omr t], 
  x1I[t] -> 0, 
  x2R[t] -> 0}}
*)
```

Note: I changed the floating-point `1.0` to an exact `1` in the OP's system.

Comment: `ComplexExpand` won't simplify the derivatives `Re[x1R'[t]]` etc. although it will simplify `Re[x1R[t]]` -- anyone know a short way to get it to do so?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in [MichaelE2's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/274888/85954), the problem is the Conjugate. An alternative to introducing real and imaginary parts is to introduce new names for the complex conjugates, I call them `x1c` and `x2c`, and solve the system for all four unknown:

```
{x1[t],x2[t]}/.DSolve[{
                 x1'[t] ==  I*omr*(x2c[t]-x2[t]), x1[0] == 1,
                x1c'[t] == -I*omr*(x2[t]-x2c[t]), x1c[0] == 1,
                 x2'[t] == -I*omr*(2*x1[t]-1), x2[0] == 0,
                x2c'[t] ==  I*omr*(2*x1c[t]-1), x2c[0] == 0
},{x1,x1c,x2,x2c},t]//FullSimplify

(* {{Cos[omr t]^2, -(1/2) I Sin[2 omr t]}} *)
```

In this case I wrote down the differential equations for `x1c` and `x2c` by hand, this could in principle be automated. Also, I assumed `omr` is real.